# hibernating not working ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hibernate

I'm using acer aspire e1 e1-572g which has ***no VGA drivers*** for Ubuntu(Linux).
when my battery go down it flasher few times in lock screen and then ***completely shuts down*** instead of hibernate according to the settings .When  I start it again it will start fresh and all my data will be lost. some internal problems massages will be shown.***NORMAL SUSPEND WORK PERFECTLY ***

Comment: What does `sudo pm-hibernate` do?

Comment: it work perfectly.

Comment: What graphics card are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By default, hibernation is disabled on Ubuntu. To re-enable hibernate, run the commands below one by one to edit the config file:

`sudo -i`

`cd /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`

`gedit com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

Copy and paste below lines into the file and save it.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After the config file has been saved, you may either log out and log in again or restart the computer to show the hibernate option in power menus.

After hibernation has been re-enabled, enter `System Settings` and select `Power`. Here you should find an option to change what the system does when the battery level reaches a critical level. Set that to `Hibernate` and all should work properly.

The original tutorial for enabling hibernation can be found [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/).